# Installing Java in /opt to avoid uninstall nightmare

Tags: java

I am currently going through the nightmare of trying to extricate all mentions of my old Java installation on Ubuntu. After many attempts, `/usr/lib/jvm` with numerous references to the old installation remains. The new installation is also not visible by the path.

Is it recommended to have Java installed and concentrated in `/opt` to avoid this kind of nightmare in the future, by simply removing the opt subdirectory?

Comment: I've never had any problems from putting JVMs from a tarball install packages into `/usr/lib/jvm`. But I also ***NEVER*** muck around ***AT ALL*** with the OS-installed JVM(s).  If you've messed up the OS installation, it's probably easier to slick the box and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the commenter that if you've boogered up the OS installed JVM, it'll be easier to reinstall the OS (after you backup your data, of course).

That said, there's not really a single "recommended" location for your use case.

- According the FHS, "Locally installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather than /usr unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software in /usr."  It sounds like you're replacing/upgrading the JVM in /usr, so this could be considered the "recommended" location.
- The use of /opt is a well-established practice, so this could also be considered the "recommended" location.
- My preference is to use $HOME/.local to install non-repository software.  It doesn't require sudo, it's easy to just delete the entire $HOME/.local directory if things get wonky, it's less likely to futz up system software.  So, this would be where I recommend you install it.

Wherever you decide to install the JVM, make sure you adjust the necessary environment variable to use the non-/usr installed JVM.